# How to identify which Space Shuttle, from a high-res cockpit photograph?

Tags: spacecraft, space-shuttle

I found this terrific photo of an STS orbiter cockpit online, however it does not mention which orbiter:

[image: Shuttle cockpit]

**How might one determine which orbiter this is**? The wear on the consoles seem to indicate that they were brushed often in a fashion that seems consistent with floating in, not walking in, so I don't think that this is a simulator. Also, the photographs of simulators don't seem to have the velcro stickers everywhere. Here is the [high res photograph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCFl5.jpg) for detail.

Comment: Sort of puts [the ADI/RCS/abort panel](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/2652/415) in context. (It's below the middle screen on the left.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Thank you. I actually did find a similar picture which [ruled out Challenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_abort_modes) but then realized that both it and the photo that you mention are before the [glass-cockpit update](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/langley/news/factsheets/Glasscockpit.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Space Shuttle Columbia, as I learned from a Google image search of the image itself (find similar), which came up with this result among others:

http://airandspace.si.edu/explore-and-learn/multimedia/detail.cfm?id=1654

I would be very interested to learn if there are ways to tell the cockpits apart from just the image, though.

From the comments:

> It's a whole lot easier to tell from looking at the aft cockpit or the middeck. In fact, after MEDS was installed, I don't know if one can tell by looking at the forward panels - Organic Marble

Comment: Very nice, thank you! What did you google for? I tried "Columbia cockpit", "Endeavour cockpit", etc but did not find that.

Comment: I googled for the image itself. You can do that by drag&dropping it into the search bar.

Comment: I had no idea!‎