# When is the self-destruct of a rocket armed?

Tags: safety, flight-termination-system, self-destruct

By this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1053/35025) I now know that most rockets have self-destruction, with SpaceX even an automated one.

And [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20657/35025) I learned that the self-destruct is also tested.

But nowhere does it say when the self-destruct is armed, let alone how long it will stay armed.

**When is the self-destruct on a missile armed?**

Answer (score 2):

For the shuttle at least (which was not a "missile" though) the range safety system was armed only shortly before it was fired.  When the shuttle range safety system was armed, a light illuminated in the crew cockpit. This was originally intended to tell the crew to eject.

> For the latter part of the program, the only Range Safety System left
> on the stack was in the Solid Rocket Boosters. So if Range Safety
> actions had to be taken in 2nd stage, the illumination of this light
> served as a backup or no-voice-comm cue to the crew to take the
> actions they had been briefed on.

[image]

Sources:

- https://space.stackexchange.com/a/7940/6944
- [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf) pp. 1.4-7 and 6.2-5